# Logging SoapUI test case failure messages using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am able to log the error messages for the assertion failures by doing the following in groovy script:

```
def soapStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["SoapRequestStep"]
for( assertion in soapStep.assertionList )
{
   if(assertion.errors != null)
   {
       for( e in assertion.errors )
       {
           log.info ${e.message}
       }
   }
}
```

However, what is the way to get the error messages for a test case failing for reasons other than assertion failures. For example,

```
testRunner.fail("Request File is empty")
```

OR

```
throw new Exception("foo")
```

Comment: Can you wrap the above code in `try { ...code here... } catch(e) { log.info( e.message ) }`?

Comment: not sure to understand exactly what you need but testRunner.fail should do the job. However, in order to tag Script Log lines in error cases, you may use log.error instead of log.info ...